# Smallest possible value of the norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal, least-squares

The vectors $ \vec{u_1} =  \begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    1 \\
1\\
1
  \end{bmatrix} $ and $ \vec{u_2} =  \begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    -1 \\
1\\
-1
  \end{bmatrix} $ are orthonormal in $ \mathbb{R}^4$.

In this exercise, I was supposed to find the parallel and normal components of the vector $ \vec{w} =  \begin{bmatrix}
    1  \\
    2 \\
-1\\
2
  \end{bmatrix} $ relative to the their span ($\vec{u_1}, \vec{u_2}$).

I found that the parallel component was (0, 2, 0, 2) and the normal component was (1, 0, -1, 0).

The next part of the exercise asks:

> What is the smallest possible value of the norm $||\vec{w}- \vec{v}|| $ if the vector $\vec{v}$ belongs to their span: $ \vec{v} \in span(\vec{u_1}, \vec{u_2}$).

Could someone help me with this part?

Answer (score 1):

Lets try the layman's approach:

$$\vec v=\begin{bmatrix}a+b\\a-b\\a+b\\a-b\end{bmatrix}\ \ (a,b\in \Bbb{R})$$
We need to find $$\min_{a,b}||\vec v-\vec w||$$Check that the values of $a,b$ for which $||\vec v-\vec w||$ will be minimum $=$ values of $a,b$ for which $||\vec v-\vec w||^2$ will be minimum. Now $$\min_{a,b}||\vec v-\vec w||^2\\=\min_{a,b}\{(a+b-1)^2+(a-b-2)^2+(a+b+1)^2+(a-b-2)^2\}\\=\min_{a,b}\{4a^2+4b^2+10-8a+8b\}\\=\min_{a,b}\{(2a-2)^2+(2b+2)^2+2\}=2 \ \ \ \text{for $a=1,b=-1$}\\\therefore\min{||\vec v-\vec w||=\sqrt 2}$$

BINGO!

Comment: I think the first part of your string of equations should be $\left(\min_{a,b}||\vec v-\vec w||\right)^2$, as the answer is clearly $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @Aweygan Well, silly mistake corrected !! Thanks

Comment: that's not a correction.

Comment: @Aweygan You mean $\min_{a,b}||\vec v-\vec w||=(\min_{a,b}||\vec v-\vec w||)^2 ?$

Comment: No, I mean $\min_{a,b}||\vec v-\vec w||\neq\min_{a,b}||\vec v-\vec w||^2$

Comment: @Aweygan Doesn't $\min_{a,b} f(a,b)$ mean the minimum values of $a,b$ for which $f(a,b)$ is minimum?

Comment: Yes, but $\min_{a,b} f(a,b)$ does not necessarily (and usually wont) equal $\min_{a,b} f(a,b)^2$.  I direct you to my first comment.

Comment: @Aweygan I know that. And I have used the equality just keeping in mind the fact that $||f||\ge 0\ \ \ \forall a,b$.

Comment: Is $\min_{x\geq4}x=\min_{x\geq4}x^2$?

Comment: @Aweygan Yes , both the functions $x$ and $x^2$ will attain their minimum value for $x=4$

Comment: No! $\min_{x\geq4}x=4$, but $\min_{x\geq4}x^2=16$

Comment: @Aweygan that's what the doubt is about then. Can you site me some reference where $\min$ function indicates not the **value of the _parameters_** but the **value of the _function_**?

Comment: This isn't worth my time, and this isn't the right place. Go relearn the definition of min and max on your own.

Comment: @Aweygan I have re-edited my answer. Is this satisfactory?

Answer (score 0):

Recall the following fact:

> The projection of a vector $\vec{w}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ onto a subspace $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is the vector in $M$ closest to $\vec{w}$.

In your case, the projection of $\vec{w}$ onto $\textrm{span}\{\vec{u}_1,\vec{u}_2\}$ is the parallel component (denoted $\vec{w}_{||}$).  So, the minimum of 
$\|\vec{w}-\vec{v}\|$ where $\vec{v}$ belongs to $\textrm{span}\{\vec{u}_1,\vec{u}_2\}$ is 
$$\|\vec{w}-\vec{v}\|=\|\vec{w}-\vec{w}_{||}\|=\|\vec{w}_\perp\|, $$
where $\vec{w}_\perp$ is the orthogonal component you found.  Thus, the answer is $\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathrm v \in \mbox{span} (\mathrm u_1, \mathrm u_2)$, then there is a $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^2$ such that $\mathrm U \mathrm x = \mathrm v$, where the columns of $\mathrm U$ are $\mathrm u_1$ and $\mathrm u_2$. However, $\mathrm w \notin \mbox{span} (\mathrm u_1, \mathrm u_2)$. Thus, we have an instance of the famous **least-squares** problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm U \mathrm x - \mathrm w \|_2^2
\end{array}$$

whose solution is

$$\hat{\mathrm x} := (\mathrm U^T \mathrm U)^{-1} \mathrm U^T \mathrm w$$

The error vector is

$$\mathrm w - \mathrm U \hat{\mathrm x} = \mathrm w - \mathrm U (\mathrm U^T \mathrm U)^{-1} \mathrm U^T \mathrm w = (\mathrm I_4 - \mathrm U (\mathrm U^T \mathrm U)^{-1} \mathrm U^T) \, \mathrm w$$

where $\mathrm P := \mathrm U (\mathrm U^T \mathrm U)^{-1} \mathrm U^T$ is the projection matrix that projects onto the column space of $\mathrm U$.

Using [SymPy](http://live.sympy.org),

```
>>> U = Matrix([[1, 1], [1, -1], [1, 1], [1, -1]])
>>> U
⎡1  1 ⎤
⎢     ⎥
⎢1  -1⎥
⎢     ⎥
⎢1  1 ⎥
⎢     ⎥
⎣1  -1⎦
>>> w = Matrix([1, 2, -1, 2])
>>> w
⎡1 ⎤
⎢  ⎥
⎢2 ⎥
⎢  ⎥
⎢-1⎥
⎢  ⎥
⎣2 ⎦
>>> P = U * (U.T * U)**-1 * U.T
>>> P
⎡1/2   0   1/2   0 ⎤
⎢                  ⎥
⎢ 0   1/2   0   1/2⎥
⎢                  ⎥
⎢1/2   0   1/2   0 ⎥
⎢                  ⎥
⎣ 0   1/2   0   1/2⎦
>>> (eye(4) - P) * w
⎡1 ⎤
⎢  ⎥
⎢0 ⎥
⎢  ⎥
⎢-1⎥
⎢  ⎥
⎣0 ⎦
>>> P * w
⎡0⎤
⎢ ⎥
⎢2⎥
⎢ ⎥
⎢0⎥
⎢ ⎥
⎣2⎦
```

The $2$-norm of the error vector is

$$\| \mathrm w - \mathrm U \hat{\mathrm x} \|_2  = \| (\mathrm I_4 - \mathrm U (\mathrm U^T \mathrm U)^{-1} \mathrm U^T) \, \mathrm w \|_2 = \| (\mathrm I_4 - \mathrm P) \, \mathrm w \|_2 = \sqrt 2$$